# IE11 Navigation Issue With Site Using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have a website which has just been designed using twitter bootstrap 3 site and HTML5 but I have an issue in IE11 as when a user logs in they should go through the following process:

1.Enter username and click 'Continue/Enter key' > goes to Password page
2.Enter password and click 'Login/Enter key' > goes to account summary page

but the screens displayed are:
1.Enter username and click 'Continue/Enter key' > goes to Password page = CORRECT
2.Enter password and click 'Login/Enter key' > goes to username page = INCORRECT

The issue is, is that once the password has been validated and is correct, the 'Enter Username' page is re-displayed **BUT** the user is actually logged in as the secure main menu is displayed.

I have identified that it's this but of jquery which is the culprit:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function DisableButton(obj)
    {
        alert(document.documentMode);
        alert(<%=Request.Browser.Version.ToString()%>);
        obj.disabled = true;
        <% if (Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer" || Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
        { %>
        if (document.documentMode < 9 || "<%=Request.Browser.Version.ToString()%>" == "7.0")
        {
            ChallengeForm.submit();
        }
        <%}
        else
        {%>
            ChallengeForm.submit();
        <%}%>
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Out of the above the following code that is stopping it from working is

```
if (document.documentMode < 9 || "<%=Request.Browser.Version.ToString()%>" == "7.0")
{
    ChallengeForm.submit();
}
```

I have tried many variations to fix this but when I fix it in IE11, I break it for IE7 then when I fix it for IE7 I end up back at my initial issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions.  I was thinking of trying to force the user to the page but i'm not sure how to do this.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: If possible, convince your key stakeholders that it's okay to stop supporting legacy browser versions. Current version minus one makes a lot more sense these days unless you are producing sites for internal networks all tied down to a particular browser.

Comment: @BillyMoat We have plans to stop using it but I have been informed we have to give the customers 6mths notice, for whatever reason

Comment: May the force be with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon investigation, it is because IE11 nows come back as Mozilla hence why it wasn't hitting my code.  by adding `Majorverion > 10` to the following line has fixed the issue for me

```
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer" || Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" || Majorverion > 10
```

Hope this helps other people